# Can You Play Two Search Cards at Once in Competitive Play

Tags: pokemon

Say I have two Profrssor’s Letters which allow me to search for two basic energy cards then shuffle my deck afterwards. In competitive play, are you able to play two of those cards or similar cards at once to look for four basic energy at once.

Comment: Is your question just whether you can look for 4 energy all at once without shuffling in between?

Comment: Yes. I don’t see what not. I was just asking if conpetitve play allowed it.

Comment: Not knowing the competitive rules, I would assume that technically you have to play one, find the energy, shuffle, then play the second one, find the energy, shuffle again, just in case there's some effect that could trigger somewhere in the middle; but possibly if your opponent allows it you could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You play Professor's Letter, search for two Energy cards in your deck.

Then you show the second Professor's Letter to your opponent, and search for two more Energy cards, without shuffling between the two.

Taking time to shuffle between the two maybe considered slow playing in tourneys, even if technically legal.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this up? While some may consider it slow play it is also skipping a step with the shuffle and not all tcg's have shortcuts that allow you to skip a step like shuffling that is going to be repeated.

Comment: I'll have to check in the OP forums if the thread about tournament shortcuts is still there, the Rules and Resources don't have a section on this, although it is something you see all the time, even on streams.